# javascript - ways to populate array with default values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm generally curious why the first example doesn't populate array with default values?

```
// first example
var arr = new Array(5);
var r = arr.map(function () { return 0; });
console.log(r); // []

// second example
var arr2 = Array.apply(null, Array(5));
var r2 = arr2.map(function () { return 0; });
console.log(r2); // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Because there's nothing in the first array except empty slots and `map` can't work on those. The second is an array of `undefined` elements which it can process.

Comment: This is valid for all programming language, when you instantiate array, it create empty slots with no values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I found on the MDN article about [Array.protoype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

> It is not called for missing elements of the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never been assigned a value).

Array elements will not be set when you initialize an array with Array constructor.

A better approach for `new Array(5)` would be `Array.from({length: 5})`, which works fine with `map`.